# How to reference implementation callback inside "run" or "apply" in Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin

How to have the implementation reference inside a "run" or "apply"

```
class MyClass : MyCallback {

    ...
    fun myMethod() {
        val myObject = MyObject()
        myObject.run {
            setCallback(this) // <-- How to have the MyCallback's reference here?
        }
    }

    override fun onMyCallback() {
        // Do something
    }
}
```

Comment: You can use @ annotation.. for example: this@MyClass

Comment: Expressions with labels generally increase complexity and worsen the maintainability of the code. It will be blocked by detekt with LabeledExpression error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As `run` is a function that takes a lambda with a receiver ([kotlin reference](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/lambdas.html#function-literals-with-receiver)) in the block that is given to `run` `this` refers to the receiver, which is in your example `myObject`.

Therefore you need to use a [qualified this](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/this-expressions.html#qualified)-expression to refer to the enclosing `MyClass`-instance. As stated in the comments you need to change your code like this:

```
class MyClass : MyCallback {

    ...
    fun myMethod() {
        val myObject = MyObject()
        myObject.run {
            setCallback(this@MyClass) // <-- qualified this
        }
    }

    override fun onMyCallback() {
        // Do something
    }
}
```

If you want to avoid labels you have to replace the `run` function. A possible alternative is `also` which instead of using a lambda with receiver gets the object as parameter:

```
class MyClass : MyCallback {

    ...
    fun myMethod() {
        val myObject = MyObject()
        myObject.also { obj ->
            //lambda without receiver, this refers to the enclosing instance of MyClass
            setCallback(this)
        }
    }

    override fun onMyCallback() {
        // Do something
    }
}
```

Comment: Expressions with labels generally increase complexity and worsen the maintainability of the code. It will be blocked by detekt with LabeledExpression error.

Comment: It is still the only way to achieve what you want. The other possibility is to avoid `run` because it uses a lambda with receiver. A possible alternative is `also`.

Answer (score 0):

recke96 already pointed out two ways to get around that problem, but here is another. Just give `this` a name outside of the lambda.

```
class MyClass  {

    fun myMethod() {
        val myObject = MyObject()
        val callback = this // <--
        myObject.run {
            setCallback(callback)
        }
    }
    // ...
}
```

Or, using `let`

```
class MyClass  {

    fun myMethod() {
        val myObject = MyObject()

        let { callback ->
            myObject.run {
                setCallback(callback)
            }
        }
    }
    // ...
}
```